# Are these conditions sufficient to guarantee positive definiteness?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, positive-definite, hermitian-matrices

Let $f: \mathbb{C}^2 \to \mathbb{C}^n$ be the map
$$ f(u, v) = (u^{n-1}, u^{n-2}v, \ldots, u^{n-k} v^{k-1}, \ldots, v^{n-1})^T$$
so that $f$ is the rational normal curve in homogeneous coordinates.

Note that the image of $f$ can be described as:
$$ \operatorname{Im}(f) = \{ c (1, z, z^2, \ldots, z^{n-1})^T; c, z \in \mathbb{C} \} \cup \{ d (0, 0, \ldots, 0, 1)^T ; d \in \mathbb{C} \}. $$

Let $H$ be an hermitian $n \times n$ matrix such that
$$ (v, Hv) > 0, $$
for any $0 \neq v \in \operatorname{Im}(f)$, where $(-, -)$ is the standard hermitian inner product on $\mathbb{C}^n$.

Are these conditions sufficient to guarantee that $H$ is positive definite? This question just popped in my head. Part of me thinks it would be too good to be true, in which case it should be easy to construct a counterexample, numerically. Another part of me thinks that the rational normal curve "twists" enough to guarantee that $H$ is positive definite.

I will think about it during the day, but I think it is an interesting question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a counter example.

For $n=3\,,$
$$
f(u,v)=(u^2,uv,v^2)\,.
$$
Let $H$ be the Hermitian matrix
$$
H=\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\0&0&0\\0&0&1\end{pmatrix}\,.
$$
which is only nonnegative semidefinite. Then, for $x\in{\rm Im}(f)\setminus\{0\}\,,$
$$
(x,Hx)=|u^2|^2+|v^2|^2>0\,.
$$